# Can we proof $B=C^*$ given $|B-Ae^{-j\omega\delta}|=|C-Ae^{+j\omega\delta}|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to ask for verification about whether this equation can be proven. If so, what is the best way to approach it? I tried this way... but I don't know how to continue on.

$$|B-Ae^{-j\omega\delta}|=|C-Ae^{+j\omega\delta}|$$
$$(B-Ae^{-j\omega\delta})(B^*-Ae^{+j\omega\delta})=(C-Ae^{+j\omega\delta})(C^*-Ae^{-j\omega\delta})$$
$$|B|^2-AB^*e^{-j\omega\delta}-ABe^{+j\omega\delta}+A^2 = |C|^2-AC^*e^{+j\omega\delta}-ACe^{-j\omega\delta}+A^2$$
$$|B|^2-2ARe\{B\times e^{+j\omega\delta}\}= |C|^2-2ARe\{C^*\times e^{+j\omega\delta}\}$$

given $B$ and $C$ are complex and $0<|A|\leq1 $.

Up to this point, I am stuck. I am not strong with math so I'm not sure how I can go about proving that
$$B=C^*$$

Is it possible? Am I approaching the problem correctly?
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any fixed complex numbers $w$ and $z$, the equation
$$|X-w|=|Y-z|$$

has an infinite solution set $\{(X,Y)\}\subseteq \Bbb C^2$ that contains more than just pairs of complex conjugates.

Indeed, picking any $X\in\Bbb C\backslash\{w\}$ and defining $r=|X-w|$, the second component $Y$ will satisfy

$$|Y-z|=r,$$

which describes a circle of radius $r$ around $z$ in the complex plane. Thus there are infinitely many second components $Y$ associated to any $X\ne w$. Specialize to $w=Ae^{-j\omega\delta}$, $z=Ae^{+j\omega\delta}$.

Comment: Thanks anon! So even despite the fact that $w$ and $z$ are $w=z^*$ complex conjugate of each other. There are still infinite solutions to this problem?

Comment: @JuniorEngie: Not just an infinite number of solutions, an infinite number of solutions $X,Y$ that are *not* complex conjugates.

Comment: Ahh, cheers for the clarification. So basically this is an open-ended problem with no 'unique' solution. Meaning $X$ and $Y$ could be any complex value and the equation still hold true. Whilst meaning that $X=Y^*$ is "one" of the possible solutions. Hmm... then I need to find a way to prove that it is one of the possible solutions now!

Comment: @JuniorEngie: Prove that $|z|=|\bar{z}|$ for any $z\in\Bbb C$. Now notice that $\overline{B-Ae^{-j\omega\delta}}=\overline{B}-Ae^{+j\omega\delta}$. (I assume you're using $j$ as the imaginary unit, and $A,\omega,\delta$ are all real.)

Comment: Thank you anon, you've helped me greatly!

Comment: @Junior: You're welcome!